# Is JQM Collapsible hidden data crawled?

Tags: google

I hope this is the proper forum for asking this  kind of question. My apologies if not.

I recently converted a web application to jQuery Mobile. My Google Analytics sessions have been reduced by 25% since the app. went live. Does Google crawl hidden data in collapsible widgets?

Choose the Services tab from the website to see the collapsible in action:
[website](http://www.bunkerhill.com)

Note: JQM modifies the markup. You can see the actual HTML by inspecting the element.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
               <div data-role="collapsible">
                    <h4>Custom Application Development</h4>
                    <p>Bunker Hill provides full-stack database driven website, desktop and mobile application development. We build all component layers from wireframes to web-services and thrive on technical challenges. Our service offerings include the following:</p>
                    <div>
                        <p class="bullet">Engaging User Interfaces that employ JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX, HTML5, CSS3, Cross-Browser Compatibility</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Multiple-Device Support - PC's, tablets, smart-phones, hand-helds,         </p>
                        <p class="bullet">Data-Modeling - the foundation of database driven applications</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Scalable Back-Ends for Mobile, Desktop and Web Applications</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Social Network Integration</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Web Services Integration - custom and those from vendor's like Google, Facebook, Yelp, Amazon, etc.</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Advanced JavaScript and jQuery Plug-in development</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Complete dedicated / virtual server / Cloud setup and deployment</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Technical team recruitment and management</p>
                        <p class="bullet">Software Code Reviews / Evaluations</p>

                    </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whether these data would be crawled or not, is depending not from the fact, that this div is collapsible, but from where is the content of this div on initial page loading:

if this div is collapsed on initial page load, and it requires a user action like click to be opened, **but the div has the content just after initial page loading** - then the content will be crawled, but will be lower ranked.

If on initial page loading the div is collapsed **and empty**, without content, and the content is loaded into div only after user action, which makes the div visible - in this case the content will not be crawled.